# Is it possible to record video and accelerometer data simultaneously on android?

Tags: android

Is it possible to record video and accelerometer data simultaneously on android?

In addition, I want the data from accelerometer around 24 values/sec.
And after that, both video and data will be synced.

Comment: "Is it possible to record video and accelerometer data simultaneously on android?" -- why not try it?

Answer (score 0):

yes...is very possible.. i have made such a program...just register your sensors...and take the values in a handler at every x milliseconds. you can attach a timestamp to your video and sensor data...so you will know which sensor data coresponds to which timeframe from movie.

Comment: Well, I already stopped this project for a while, but thank you any way.

Comment: @Dany's I don't know anything about android programming but I would be highly interested in a sketch (or even better a workable source code) of what to do here. Would you be kind enough to elaborate a bit on your answer?

Comment: Without a link to some code, or at least some more elaboration, I don't see how this answer is in anyway useful.